# How does Stack Overflow have questions appear in Google so quickly?

Tags: google, sitemap, google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StackOverflow and Google search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/stackoverflow-and-google-search)

I have noticed while asking questions on Stack Overflow that they appear in Google almost instantly.

How does SO do this?

Is it a feed or an auto-updated site map?