# Why does Google index pages of my blog in seconds, while pages on the rest of the website take longer to get indexed

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I have a questions and answers website in Portuguese about a specific subject.

My Q&A website also have a blog, on a sub-directory like `www.site.com/articles`.

I had not written on the blog for almost a year, and a few days ago, I wrote a new article, and for my surprise it got indexed by Google in less than a minute. After this, I continued writing new articles. And they are always indexed in less than a minute. It's amazing.

---

By the other hand, the home page of the website, where the new questions added by the users are shown, was last indexed by Google on May, 17.

I would appreciate your opinions about why does Google is indexing in seconds the blog, and not behaving on the same way for the home page and questions published by the users.

Another point to consider, is that due to a problem with the server, before yesterday, the full website went off for over 5 hours and I didn't notice it. After solving the problem, I wrote a new article to test Google, and for my surprise again it was indexd again in less than one second. So, It's really crazy and good this behaving of Google.

Comment: Is the blog, Wordpress? If yes, the same happens to me. It takes minutes to get a post indexed and roughly 2 to 4 days for an article on the main site even though there are more updates and interesting stuff on the site. I too would like to know how WP does that!

Comment: yes. Wordpress.

Answer (score 8):

Wordpress is set to ping Google whenever you write a new post.

From http://wordpress.org/support/topic/google-blog-pinging

> Settings->Writing. At the bottom you'll find a list of "Update Services".
>
> The default is to ping the pingomatic server, which then pings a dozen or more other places for you, Google included. However, if you want to ping Google directly, then remove pingomatic and add http://blogsearch.google.com/ping/RPC2 to that list.

If you want to do pings the same way that WordPress does, it looks like http://pingomatic.com/ is available for anybody to use.

Comment: So, this means I can create a script to ping google also...

Comment: Yes, I added a link to pingomatic.com in my answer.

Comment: FWIW you can do the same with a Sitemap file (including pinging programmatically) -- you don't need to artificially create an RSS feed if your website doesn't already have one.