# Is it possible to programmability ping search engines for specific updated pages?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, url-inspection-tool

I spent a lot of hours into making my website useful to the user and extremely friendly. However, Google seems to not update the indexed content and is not indexing new pages fast enough. The website is contently being updated and I am looking for ways to get search engine robots to visit me more often due to the content update of the website.

I have an automated job that runs every 20 minutes which adds new or updates existing pages on my website. Additionally, once a day, I regenerate the site maps and ping google with my sitemap-index URL to inform it that there is an update to the sitemap.

However, Google does not index my pages as fast as it should or I would like it to. I am wondering if there is a way to programmability ping google every time a page is updated or added? For example, when the job added 10 new pages and updates 20 other pages, then I would ping google and with the 30 updated pages so the indexed content is updated.

It seems that the "Inspect any URL" service in Google Search Console does that. Is it possible to automatically use that service to inform Google with the new content? or is there an alternative way of pinging search engines with the new content?

Comment: See also [Why does Google index pages of my blog in seconds, while pages on the rest of the website take longer to get indexed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48910/why-does-google-index-pages-of-my-blog-in-seconds-while-pages-on-the-rest-of-th)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, can I use pingomatic.com to alert the search engines about the a page that isn't a page or blog on wordpress? my site isn't a wordpress.

Comment: You can set up an rss feed to support PubSubHubbub (WebSub) and submit it as a sitemap. People like Google can subscribe to the feed. When you add new content your system pings subscribers with what is new. It's not simple to set up, and no guarantee it works. It's been a long time since I played with it.