# Classified ads website ranking very low in google indexing

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, google-index, seo-audit

We have a large classified ads website with a good sitemap and robots.txt.
We have good content google crawls us 4 times per second but.... we dont get indexed by Google and our new advertisement post appears in SERP after 2 or 3 days what should we do to get index in hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, forget sitemap and `robots.txt`. Those are fun, but not magic, they just help on a technical level for hard to reach content.

Second: Google doesnt work in "hours", Google works in "a few days". If you change something, it can take up to a few days, they're not waiting until you update something. For bigger/more popular sites this will be more often, but a 'normal' websites take a few days ([Why do SO questions appear so quickly](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/how-do-stackoverflow-questions-appear-in-google-search-results-so-quickly)).

Then, I don't want to be rude, but if you appear in SERP page 2 or 3, you probaly don't have good content, because if you would, you would be on page one.

I recommend you use a few SEO score websites, there are free ones. Do a few of those. It might be worth your money to invest in a paid report as those give you much much more info.

Comment: but many sites like SO or Ebay and and and much more get appear in serp after a few hours

Comment: so what sO or site like it do that get get appear and we dont

Comment: Is your site in the same league as SO or Ebay, or are you a 'normal' site?

Comment: yes we are a large ad site with huge traffic and we really did every thing for our seo

Comment: One never did "every thing" for SEO ;) Clearly there is room for improvement.

Comment: yeah :D always there is a room , I meant as much as we could in a large scale