# How can I place keywords at the begining of a title and have it look natural?

Tags: seo, keywords, title

As per [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title), the first word in the `<title>` tag is usually treated with more importance than the rest of the `<title>` tag.

How can I write naturally looking titles with the keyword that I'm targeting being the first word in the title, without resorting to doing something like this: `keyword - real title`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For many pages you can't, not without making the title either under-descriptive or really awkward and spammy at least. Front-loading is a really unnatural way to write.

If you have general topics, like Wikipedia pages, then it's easy to do something like:

- Labradors
- Labrador training
- A/C repair

But most blog articles, news posts, etc. out there aren't generic encyclopedic knowledge though. If you're lucky, you can make the title a declarative statement or proposition:

- Audis are fun to drive
- SHA1 vulnerability found

You can also define the keyword using a colon:

- SEO: It is essential for your website.
- Stack Exchange: the best website online.

But if the topic has a subject *and* an object or multiple subjects then it becomes unnatural to try to clump the topical nouns immediately together at the front of the sentence/title:

- Mark Walberg was Marky Mark -> Mark Walberg Marky Mark was
- Beyonce wins Song of the Year at 2009 Grammys -> Beyonce's Grammy 2009 Song of the Year win
- ["Things You Should Never Do, Part I"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html) -> Software Development Rewrite Code You Never Do Should
- The Complete Guide to Writing Front loaded Titles -> Front loaded Title Writing, the Complete Guide
- ["Why File Upload Forms Are A Major Security Threat"](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat.htm) -> File Upload Forms Security Threat Major

As you can see, the front loaded variants are much less user-friendly/readable. In most cases, you end up just removing the verbs/conjunctions/articles/etc. (or placing them at the end, where they serve zero purpose, and you might as well just leave them out) and sound like someone trying to speak a language they're not fluent in.

As you can probably guess, I'm not a big fan of this search engine policy. I don't think the Google engineers or whoever came up with it understands how people use language, and he's definitely not a writer himself.

Answer (score 1):

Use skills in english to prioritize. Make your titles focal to what it is, how it's used, and other informatives. Things like *"Keywords fit Subkeyword in Trikeyword"* or *"Keywords are used for Keywording and Subkeywording"*. Getting the singular form is easy too, just use an "A" like in a meta: *"A keyword will make your subkeyword better. Available in red, blue, or camouflage."*

Honestly though as Bhoomika states, it doesn't matter where or how it is used, even in longtail. If there are helper adjectives before it, Google will still treat it as a high power string. Also, **Google cuts up page titles anyways**, so using 1 string is irrelevant for MANY queries -- ie it won't even use that title and instead make its own based on the matches contained in your static title.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your keyword in the long-tail. It creates good impression as well as looks natural.