# Correct formatting for page title

Tags: seo, title

I have a website that speaks about videogames, and I have news, guides, reviews and articles. **Which is the best format for the `title`?**

Let me explain better with an example. Said that I have a guide, the actual title for the page have this format:

> Name of the game - Guide - Title of the guide.

I would like to know if is it better to use another format like:

> Title of the guide - Name of the game - Guide

Or something else.

Comment: See also:  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless game names are all very short - less than 8 characters - you will be best off with

`Title of the guide - Name of the game`

For one, many visitors may have multiple tabs open, and the first few words of the `<title>` tag will appear on the tab in most browsers. So if the game name is longer than the few characters allowed in the tab, they will only see the game name there - not the particular guide they are looking at. They're likely to have other tabs about that game open so the game name is then less relevant when they're trying to switch between tabs and identify what each is about.

Similarly, visitors using a screen reader can more quickly tell what the specific page is about if you have the most specific information at the beginning. So instead of having to listen to `Long name of the game (dash) Guide (dash) Actual information that is specific to this page` they can listen to `Information specific to this page (Game)`. Since the specific piece of content you're talking about is a guide, I would expect the word "guide" to be part of `Title of the guide` and not a separate word in the title - thus my recommendation to shorten the title to 2 pieces of information rather than 3.

I think you will also find this structure best for SEO. Rather than front-loading the game name, you can target longer-tail keywords by having the `Title of the guide` at the beginning, and of course you'll have the name of the game later in the title and woven throughout the content itself. You're not trying to compete for searches for `Game name` - these pages should instead be competing for `Title of the guide for game name` which is what this suggested title structure positions you best to compete for.

Comment: Thank you for your exaustive answer! I'll try to do that for sure....I was thinking too that could be batter in this way, the only thing that was keeping to do the change is that in my DB the title never contain the world guide because i knew that it was already part of the title. Do you think that i'll have to change the titles? Maybe is still usefull to rank for keywords like : Guide Name of the game. Ty very much for your support i really appreciate :)

Comment: You should probably do keyword research to find out whether people are searching for "guides" or rather for the names of specific problems. It really depends on the way your audience searches. Even if not, I do think the word "guide" could be valuable since it will show in the link to your site that your page is specifically about solving that problem, so yes, you probably want to update all your titles to include it. It may help to export a spreadsheet, update them, and mass import so they're all consistent.

Comment: Thank You! I will make this changes! Your help was very usefull :)

Comment: @raffaeledelvecchio I've reopened the question since this question can be answered differently as WebElaine has. If you're satisfied with her answer, please accept it - that will give you reputation points as well.